# Relating text buffer to text size in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography

I'm working with QGIS 2.16. When I create a map, I often use a white buffer around text of various size. The thing not evolving is the buffer size : the rendered text is sometimes a bit strange visually and the buffer is **looking like** it's not the same size on every text (even if it is if you mesure it). How to avoid this visual effect ?

[image: Normal]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Create a **data defined field** (Font_size) and set the font size in the label properties to be dependent on this field.
- Create a **virtual field** (VRT_Buffer) with the following formula : `to_real( "Font_Size") /15`
- Set the buffer size property to point towards this virtual field :

[image: Buffer settings]

You get a text with font size depending buffer, changing interactively when you change the font size with the label tools.

[image: text with variable buffer]