# QGIS - manually adjust polygon labels

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling

I was wondering whether in QGIS you can break up a long text label attached to a polygon object into two lines and then move the label manually?  The label appears in small text as the polygon is small, so as well as this is there a way of increasing the font size of the new label?

Comment: This is three different questions, all of which have been asked and answered already.

Answer (score 1):

You can make centroids from polygon, and then wrap on character label with space or letter you  choose to wrap or you can try this method:
[Relating text buffer to text size in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210370/relating-text-buffer-to-text-size-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

If the label used is from one field only, then you can specifiy a sign like / or _ or whatever that breaks the label in two lines. (label menu -> second tab -> first field on top)

If the label is created from two fields, then you can use "field1" \n "field2" to break the values in two lines.

In both cases, you will be able to move the labels with X and Y coordinates in the centroid shapefile like nagib said.